# VBA Code to Randomly Apply Fill Colours to Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and I am currently starting out from scratch, however, I was looking for a code that can automatically fill cells with randomly assigned colours.

I need to code to be applied to a column of data and have it give each cell when filled with a value a different colour but colour cells with the same entry the same...

Hope this makes sense?  An example would be:

1. Cat - Randomly Applies Yellow
2. Dog - Randomly Applies Blue
3. Fish - Randomly Applies Green
4. Cat -  Applies Yellow Again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the overall aim (or is this it?)  and what have you tried? There may be a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.  Essentially I am building up a ventilation system and each row in the column will allow me to assign a certain room to a certain ventilation system.  As the systems increase in number, the number of systems may also increase and, they may have numerous names.  I can use conditional formatting but it won't be efficient to update this everytime I add a new system.  If the VBA code can recognise I've added a different system and apply a different colour to it that would speed things up greatly.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following.

It uses a dictionary to collect the unique "words" and randbetween with dictionary item count to generate an associated colour. Conditional formatting rules are applied using the distinct "words"

**Notes:**

1. You might want to improve the random colour generation part (at present range is limited and you may occasionally get very dark formats - though you could run the macro again)
2. Make range selection more robust as start position is hard coded at present and later parts of code use this start position as well
3. Required, for early binding, reference to Microsoft scripting runtime to be added via VBE>Tools>References. I have included one example of how to use late binding (commented out). If using late binding you would need to specify Object instead of Dictionary for parameters and function return types (where dictionary returned).
4. Assumes data starts in A2 at present (sheet 7)

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FormatMatchingNames()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, formatRange As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Sheet7")       'change as appropriate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = GetLastRow(wsTarget)
    If Not lastRow <= 2 Then
        Set formatRange = wsTarget.Range("A2:A" & lastRow) 'Adjust as required
    Else
        MsgBox "End row is before start row"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary

    Set codeColoursDictionary = GetDistinctCodeCount(formatRange.Value2)
    wsTarget.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    AddFormatting formatRange, codeColoursDictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetDistinctCodeCount(ByVal sourceData As Variant) As Dictionary 'as object if latebound
''LATE binding
'    Dim distinctDict As Object
'    Set distinctDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

''Early binding add reference to VBE > tools > references > Microsoft scripting runtime
    Dim distinctDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set distinctDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentCode As Long

    For currentCode = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)
        If Not distinctDict.Exists(sourceData(currentCode, 1)) Then
            distinctDict.Add sourceData(currentCode, 1), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(13434828, 17777777) + distinctDict.Count
        End If
    Next currentCode

    Set GetDistinctCodeCount = distinctDict
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet) As Long
    With wsTarget
           GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change to column containing last row up to which you want to format
    End With
End Function

Public Sub AddFormatting(ByVal formatRange As Range, ByVal codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary)  'note pass as object if late binding
    Dim key As Variant, counter As Long
    For Each key In codeColoursDictionary.keys
        counter = counter + 1
        With formatRange
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A2=""" & key & """"
            .FormatConditions(counter).StopIfTrue = False
            With .FormatConditions(counter).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = codeColoursDictionary(key)
            End With
        End With
    Next key
End Sub
```

---

**Sheet:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a quick one, my system references are a bit more complicated than shown i.e 
3.O-1/GF-H/-/AHU/003
3.O-1/B2-H/-/AHU/006
3.O-1/B2-H/-/AHU/005
Will the code still differentiate these or, does it only work for words that are within the English dictionary?

Comment: I did and it works however in practice this will be difficult to use.  I have a ‘datasheet’ worksheet where I list all my system references in a table and on another 'calculation' sheet use a drop-down menu to assign this system to a room.  Can we create another column adjacent to the system references on the 'datasheet' and input numbers there relating to colours rather than randomly generate them using the dictionary like you did in the above code? i.e.
System Ref      |     Colour Code
System 1          |     1
System 2          |     2
System 3          |     3

Comment: I'm struggling to visualize but if you want to set pre-fixed colours then simply amend the code above to not use Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(13434828, 17777777) + distinctDict.Count  , and instead put your predefined colour codes here.  But you will then have to load your dictionary from the sheet where you hold the pairs of system | colour code.

Comment: Is there anyway that i can send you an example?  I am really green to VBA and this is over my head at the moment.  PS thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Maybe in the morning when I have more time to dedicate to thinking it through. It is difficult as you have not included a realistic data sample to work with. I don't really want to keep writing solutions and have you change requirements, but  I also don't want to seem unhelpful (that comment is not just aimed at you! I am being a little grumpy. Sorry.)

Comment: Ok. fully noted.  If you still feel like helping tomorrow then I can send you an example and fully annotate what I am looking to achieve.  Thanks and good night.

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: Sub ColourCells()


Dim lastrow As Long
Dim FormatRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range


Sheet1.Range("g2:h1000").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells.Range("g2", "h1000")_.Find(what:="*", After:=Range("h1000"), Lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
Set FormatRange = Sheet1.Range("G2:H" & lastrow)

For Each Cell In FormatRange

Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet1.Range("P4:q18"), 2, False)

Next

End Sub>

Comment: I also do not yet know how to post correctly in this forum and I apologise for this.

Comment: Yes.  I have the sample workbook.  The main tabs to review are Data_Sheet & Vent_Calcs.  I have highlighted in red what I am looking for.  I got the earlier code to work but i feel its a bit inefficient. How do you attach sheets?

Comment: Lol. Actually I called my code inefficient, also took me all day to write mine :-(

Comment: Just kidding. Where is this workbook? Can you load as xlsx with no macros and include the code as a pastebin ? https://pastebin.com/